# What is a the best way to generate QrCode in SpringBoot and scan it using Angular?

Tags: spring-boot, backend, qr-code

I am working on a project where I have to generate QrCode in SpringBoot, after some research I've find zxing API but before jumping into any implementation, I want to know how people handle qrcode in SpringBoot out there.

Comment: Here is a good read about QR Code in Spring: https://www.baeldung.com/java-generating-barcodes-qr-codes

Comment: @Mousse I want to integrate barcode reader to my spring boot project and I am searching proper library. which library did you prefer? can you explain library with your preference reasons?